# Put element to the right side of a div

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know how I can put these divs to the right side of the White div.
http://prntscr.com/5jmm6q

As you can see, it stacks under the left div, and I want it to be to the upper right side.
When I use float:right, here is what I get:
http://prntscr.com/5jmo1p

That is not what I want :/

Here is my CSS code:

```
#leftmenu {
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    height:auto;
    width:150px;
    background-color:gray;
    padding:2px;
}

#leftmenu .titlebox {
    height:20px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:black;
}

#leftmenu .titlebox .text {
    margin-left:10px;
    font-family:OswaldL;
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
}

/*Now, here is the part that I want to move to the upper right side*/

#rightmenu {
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    height:auto;
    width:250px;
    background-color:gray;
    padding:2px;
}

#rightmenu .titlebox {
    height:20px;
    width:250px;
    background-color:black;
}

#rightmenu .titlebox .text {
    margin-left:10px;
    font-family:OswaldL;
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="base">
    <section style="color: black;">
        <div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text"><?php echo NOM_SITE;?></div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">MENU</div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

        <div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">MENU</div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>



        <div id="rightmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">MENU</div></div>
            <div class="droite_text">
                <li><a href="forum.php?id=1">DATA</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="rightmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">MENU</div></div>
            <div class="droite_text">
            DATA
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: some html also needed to introspect.

Comment: guess you need to use float: left. Add your html to the post

Comment: Can you post your HTML code as well?

Comment: There you go, I posted the HTML :)

Comment: can you change the html structure slightly ?

Comment: You have the same id name multiple times (ex. #rightmenu and #leftmenu) which is not allowed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit change in HTML

```
<div id="base">
    <section style="color: black;">
      <!-- added new div here -->
  <div class="leftMain"><div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text"><?php echo NOM_SITE;?></div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">MENU</div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

        <div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">MENU</div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="rightmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">MENU</div></div>
            <div class="droite_text">
                <li><a href="forum.php?id=1">DATA</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="rightmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">MENU</div></div>
            <div class="droite_text">
            DATA
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS changes

```
 .leftMain{
     float:left;
    }
#rightmenu {
   float:right;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2oqbh17L/1/

Comment: You have the same id name multiple times (ex. #rightmenu and #leftmenu) which is not allowed :) Change them from ids to class :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see the example.http://jsfiddle.net/fL5gg70o/

```
#leftmenu {
 float:left;
}
```

And for right div:

```
#rightmenu {
 float:right;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put everything You want to have on left to one container `#left` for example and add float: left to it. Everything You want to have on right put in `#right` and add float: right

Also You have some mistakes in code (for example many elements with `#leftmenu` id - id should be uniqe

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rwspycft/1/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to float those elements. However, if you float them they will flow out of the document flow. I'd try messing around with:

```
clear: both;
```

or/and

```
overflow: hidden;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afgmyw4t/

Click the JSfiddle I have recreated your problem. I floated the elements left, and right. Then added clear:both; on the left elements to keep them within the document flow. They may need a few styling tweaks, if you have any trouble please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap menus around separate div and set the float properties for both.

```
.rightt {
    float: right;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}

.leftt {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

<div id="base">
    <section style="color: black;">
        <div class='leftt'>
        <div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text"><?php echo NOM_SITE;?></div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">MENU</div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

        <div id="leftmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">MENU</div></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">DATA</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
</div>

<div class='rightt'>
        <div id="rightmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">MENU</div></div>
            <div class="droite_text">
                <li><a href="forum.php?id=1">DATA</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightmenu">
            <div class="titlebox"><div class="text">MENU</div></div>
            <div class="droite_text">
            DATA
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v0t9p072/1/)**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you code, but when I use it, here is what I get: http://prntscr.com/5jmu47

I want it to be to the upper side, any ideas on how I can solve it?

Comment: @M4DNE55 In that case, just define a width for both the right and left containers. Updated the answer and the fiddle. Check it out.