# How to align element to right side of div box?

Tags: html, css, css-position

## How to align element to right side of div box?

#### My div

```
<div id="foo">
    <div id="tree">Some Text here</div>
</div>
```

#### My css

```
#foo {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #5e5e5e;
}

#tree {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #000000;
}
```

I need **tree** placed at top-right side of **foo**.

Comment: [Do none of these work for you?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=align+element+right+side+div) This oft asked question is oft answered all over SO and the internet.

Comment: You can use Float property of CSS like "float: right;". Check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600267/put-element-to-the-right-side-of-a-div

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this. One way is to add an automatic left margin to the tree:

```
margin-left: auto;
```

Another option would be to apply `float: right;` to the tree, which may or may not result in the content flow you need.

And finally, my recommendation honestly would be to just use flexbox.

### Margin Example

```css
#foo {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #5e5e5e;
}

#tree {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #000000;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
    <div id="tree">Some Text here</div>
</div>
```

### Float Example

```css
#foo {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #5e5e5e;
}

#tree {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #000000;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
    <div id="tree">Some Text here</div>
</div>
```

### Flex Example

```css
#foo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #5e5e5e;
}

#tree {
    display: flex;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
    <div id="tree">Some Text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added a couple other options in case the content flow isn't what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Give float:right to #tree.

```css
#foo {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #5e5e5e;
}

#tree {
 float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #000000;
}
```

```html
  <div id="foo">
  <div id="tree">Some Text here</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a `position: relative / absolute` combination:

```css
#foo {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #5e5e5e;
    position:relative;
}

#tree {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #000000;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
    <div id="tree">Some Text here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with `position:absolute`

```css
#foo {
        display: block;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        position: relative;
        background: #5e5e5e;
    }

    #tree {
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        background: #000000;
        color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="foo">
    <div id="tree">Some Text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If i set position:absolute, it's positioning to page, not #foo

Comment: Basic rule of position: absolute, works only with relative position of parent. Please go through the #foo css

Answer (score 0):

Update your css like this. **#tree** div will always be at the top right corner of **#foo**

```css
 #foo {
        display: block;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background: #5e5e5e;
        position: relative;
    }

    #tree {
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        background: #000000;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```